# Apple Push Notification Sounds

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, apple-push-notifications, persistent

When a push notification is received, is there any way to make the sound play persistently until the user takes an action -- like pressing the OK button -- when the app is NOT active?

I'd like to send a push message and have the alert sound keep playing until the user responds to mimic the behavior of a pager.

Is this possible?  Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

not possible. See apple docs http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 2):

The sound will not play persistantly, it will simply "chime" once.